# I'm unable to find /usr/share/plymouth/themes/

Tags: directory, plymouth

I'm thinking about customizing a theme for Ubuntu 12.10. The problem is that I've looked through the /usr/share directory and I haven't been able to find the Plymouth folder. What can I do to get the folder?

Comment: Have a look here askubuntu.com/questions/173329/what-alternatives-are-available-to-replace-the-purple-boot-splash-screen/173340#173340

Comment: Stephen, it's no longer a problem now. I could have sworn I put "solved" in the title.

Comment: We don't put solved in the title of posts; an answer is marked as the solution with a green tick (as below), so I've edited your question again.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that.

Comment: Thats ok- welcome to ask Ubuntu! it's just a bit different here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the folder with the following command:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/plymouth/themes
```

On the second thought, `/lib/plymouth/themes/` may be what you need.

Make a backup of it before customizing with

```
sudo cp -r /lib/plymouth/themes /lib/plymouth/themes-backup
```